# How can get value of element using corresponding currentItemId

Tags: javascript, .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

I have `currentItemId`. I want to use `currentItemId` to get value of element (which contains `currentItemId`). Is it possible?

Currently I am using this code:

```
function Custom_AddListMenuItems(m, ctx)
{

current = currentItemID;
var temp1 = document.getElementById('current');
alert(temp1);

CAMOpt(m,'AssetDetails (new window)','javascript:window.open(\'http://infpw03403:15000/Lists/Asset%20Repository/DispForm.aspx?ID='+temp1+'\')','/_layouts/images/LIST.GIF');
return false;
}
```

If there is any other method please let me know.

Comment: can you please post your HTML code

Comment: I am not using html code.. its use in sharepoint 2007 webpart page.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to pass the variable(current) to getElementById instead of the string 'current'

```
var temp1=document.getElementById(current);
alert(temp1.value);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your HTML page the element must have its id="currentItemId".
Then only you can use

`var temp1 = document.getElementById(currentItemId).value;`